# Problems with Nested Objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to create a nested model with Backbone and have a couple of issues:
I'll follow with the example in the backbone documentation: say I have a Mailbox Collection, and each Mailbox can have a collection of Messages.  I want to see and work on these nested lists in my app.  First - I alter my Mailbox model as noted in the backbone documentation.:

```
var Mailbox = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.messages = new Messages;
    this.messages.url = '/mailbox/' + this.id + '/messages';
    this.messages.bind("reset", this.updateCounts);
  },
});
```

My first question, when I populate data in the model with a server call (which I do with eager loading - I pass in the Mailboxes and nested Messages)  I can load the data into attributes on each Mailbox, but when looking at it in a javascript debugger, I see the array of nested data in my object's attributes, but I don't see the data loaded into the actual nested collection.   Am I doing something wrong?  It's like there's two different sets of information.

Second question - when I show a nested index view - I want to show a list of Mailboxes each with a nested list of Messages - I try to use nested views with backbone, only my nested views repeat the views of other objects from the outer view - creating this strange grouping of duplicate views everywhere.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.  Might anyone have any pointers here?

Is there any good definitive guidance on creating not just models, but models, collections and views with nested objects in backbone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out answers to both my questions on the IRC channel for documentcloud..

For the first question, it's simply an exercise in exposing that data.  You can either create a global variable (of a collection or router) and expose the data there... That's just up to the user.

For the second question, I had an issue where I was using the rails-backbone gem, and when using the scaffolding for that gem to create nested views, you wind up using jquery to append views in multiple places, because the gem is not expecting to have multiple tbody tags within a document.